# SQL Server : Rollback without BEGIN TRANSACTION

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Is there a way we can rollback to previous state of the transaction using ROLLBACK without `BEGIN TRANSACTION`?

```
delete from table1;
ROLLBACK
```

Message:

> *The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.*

Any input would be of great help.

Thanks !!!

Comment: everything has a rule. When you've not got on the bus, how do you want to get down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand on gerrytans answer when you explicitly set IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON, you can use a ROLLBACK. See the [MSDN doco](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187807.aspx) related to this. Note that this isn't the default [autocommit transaction mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187878%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

This allows me to run a statement like;

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON

INSERT INTO my_table (item_type, start_date_time)
VALUES ('TEST', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

ROLLBACK

-- Shouldn't return the 'TEST' value inserted above.
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY start_date_time DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

As SQL server error tells you -- no you can't. And many people would be curious why would you want that in the first place.

Keep in mind SQL server has an implicit transaction -- that is for DML you issue without explicit BEGIN TRAN, SQL server will start and finish a transaction for you behind the screen.

A common usage of ROLLBACK is for error handling. If somewhere in the middle of the transaction you realize you cannot proceed further due to bad user input or other reason -- then a reasonable action is to ROLLBACK to return to the starting point

The worst thing that can happen is leave your data state 'somewhere in the middle'.

Answer (score 3):

You must have a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` before you can use the `ROLLBACK` command.  You can't go back to the previous state.

Comment: Yes , but does sql server supports any form of rollback without BEGIN TRANSACTION .

Comment: Could you provide and example or a link to how Oracle supports this?

Comment: I think Oracle defaults with a transaction.  SQL Server default is to not have a transaction.  You must explicitly define the transaction.

Answer (score -1):

The best option, not to suffer, put
BEGIN TRAN
QUERY

In that case it is not necessary
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).