# Roll-back last UPDATE SQL query in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have accidentally executed the query:

```
UPDATE TableName 
SET Name='Ram'
```

How can I undo this change?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Was the query inside a transaction? if no then you can't!

Comment: No; you can't - please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472785/sql-server-rollback-without-begin-transaction (unless you used a transaction)

Comment: You can't rollback your last query if it was not in opened transaction. So, in this case, you could only restore your database from backup.

Comment: Bad News... as others mentioned above, SQL Server has an auto-commit functionality which by default makes all DML statements concrete without having to run a COMMIT; command. What you need to do is call your DBA and see what table restore options are available to you. Most databases will have overnight snapshots saved so if your query was devastating enough, the DBA can rollback the entire table.

Comment: Dont ask questions on mistakes you need to talk to your DBA's or whoever manages the database ASAP to fix it. In the future if you haven't tested it put it into a select statement and test or in a Tranaction block.See answer.

Comment: If you have a backup (which in production environment is mandatory) perhaps you could repare your table using a restore of that backup. You can write queries that involve more than one database in your sql server instance (by using database_name.schema_name.table_name when referring to tables). Before attempting that though, take a safety-backup of the database you wish to manually repare (you don't want to screw it up even more). If you don't have a backup of the database, you are SOL.

Comment: In reference to my previous comment: restore you backup to a database with a **new name**, don't blindly restore it over the database you want to fix.

Answer (score 3):

Before running update, or deletes especially always test them. For an delete put the statement into a select block.

```
SELECT COUNT(NAME)
FROM TableName
WHERE
```

And make sure the number of records returned match what you are wanting to delete. FOr an update it is a little more envolved. You will have to use a transaction.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
UPDATE TableName
SET Name = 'Ram'

SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE Name = 'Ram'
--Rollback Transaction
--Commit Transaction
```

Based on what you did in the transaction just run the first part leaving commit and rollback commented out then the select will let you validate everything worked correctly then if it is what you want highlight and run just the COMMIT without the comments if it isn't what you wanted then highlight an run just the ROLLBACK without comments to undo it and try again. Hope this helps in the future.